# How much disk space does it take to run a blockchain explorer?

Tags: bitcoin-core, development, blockexplorer

I understand that you can use existing explorers like blockchain.info for quick access to individual transactions and address balances, however I would like to run an explorer of my own Like [Hyperledger](https://github.com/hyperledger/blockchain-explorer) or [iquidus](https://github.com/iquidus/explorer) -- So that I can have quick access to indexed account balances.

I need to know how much space this will take initially -- And understand it will vary based on how big the chain has gotten, but a rough ratio of block height to disk space would be quite useful here.

Comment: Short answer, about 200GB to have all bitcoin blocks and addresses transactions.

Comment: @Adam - So for Bitcoin right now which uses about 200GB on it's own for the blockchain, it would be another 200GB for the index? 1:1?

Comment: You might end up with a little more for the index, since the node's storage is quite compact. Most explorers tend to expand the serialized transactions and blocks into more easily indexed data structures